# Storing currentDate in database

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the NOW() function to store date in the database. But when i check the values in the database, the date is something else.

```
   $sql="INSERT INTO feedback_comments 
       (posted_by, email, comments_text, comment_date)
   VALUES
       ('$postedBy','$emailID','$message',NOW())";
```

Comment: Timezone discrepancies between PHP and MySQL, most likely.

Comment: Can you provide some e.g

Comment: what type is 'comment_date' ? what does it show? what do you expect?

Comment: comment_date is database field of type Date. The above code is included in a php file which is called when the form is submitted. I want to store the date and time when the user submits the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it always off by the same amount? If so, it's likely to be either a configuration difference in times between your database and PHP environment, or even two different times if they're running on separate boxes.

The other possibility is that the type of the column you're inserting in to is not correct. In that case, you'll probably get something like `20071215235026.000000` instead of `'2007-12-15 23:50:26'`.

Comment: They are runnign on the same host. How am I suppose to change the settings.

Comment: You can try http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html - the first for PHP, the second for MySQL, but you should make sure that actually _is_ the problem first.

Comment: I referred to your 2nd link. But i cant figure it out from where am I suppose to change them. ie. Can you provide me the complete procedure. That links shows the command we can use but not the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `current timestamp` as the field type so with out insertion it will record the date time